# Display multiple images horizontally aligned keeping original images sizes

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

How can I plot multiple images horizontally aligned keeping original images sizes with matplotlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subplots with matplotlib to build a grid which will display one image per case. You can use figsize to adapt the overall size of the grid to get to your original image size.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as  np
# creating some data for the plots (from matplotlib simple plots)
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
# creating the grid
num_rows = 4
num_cols = 2
num_images = num_rows*num_cols
plt.figure(figsize=(2*2*num_cols, 2*num_rows)) # here you can adapt the size of the figure
for i in range(num_images):
    plt.subplot(num_rows, num_cols, i+1) # adding a subplot
    plt.plot(t, s) # adding a plot to the subplot
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```